# Include html tag in jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
  var str = $(location).attr('href');
  var myString = str.substr(str.indexOf("?id=")+4);
  $.getJSON(
    'http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', 
    { get_param: 'value' }, 
    function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (myString == (data[i]["Nr SAT"])) {
          $('body').append($('<p id="data">').html(data[i]["Data"]));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Tipo Servizio: '+ data[i]["Tipo Servizio"]));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Stato: '+ data[i]["Stato"]));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Attributo: '+ data[i]["Attributo"]));
        }           
      }
    }
  );
});
```

If after the control `if (myString == (data[i]["Nr SAT"]))` i would  write tag html like `<p>`, in which way i can include it in the function??

Comment: You want to add to the body a `<p>` element? and after that append to that `<p>` each content?

Comment: for example i want and the tag <hr> between the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var str = $(location).attr('href');
  var myString = str.substr(str.indexOf("?id=")+4);
  $.getJSON(
    'http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', 
    { get_param: 'value' }, 
    function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (myString == (data[i]["Nr SAT"])) {
          $('body').append($('<p id="data">').html(data[i]["Data"]+"<hr />"));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Tipo Servizio: '+ data[i]["Tipo Servizio"]+"<hr />"));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Stato: '+ data[i]["Stato"]+"<hr />"));
          $('body').append($('<p>').html('Attributo: '+ data[i]["Attributo"]));
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```